# Changing Nginx Log File Location

Tags: nginx

I can't get any changes in the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf http block to be used. I'm starting with the simplest thing - I want to modify the name of  access.log to something else (ie a.log). It is a vanilla nginx install (no custom config files yet). Here's what I know:

- changing a value in the head of nginx.conf does affect the configuration (changing worker_processes 4 to worker_processes 2 does change the # of workers)
- Making a syntax error in nginx.conf's http block *does* cause nginx to throw an error on restart
- Changing access_log to access_log /var/log/nginx/a.log does not modify the location of the log, and nginx in fact continues logging to /var/log/nginx/access.log

Here is a snippet of my nginx.conf file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
}

http {
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/a.log;
        #....
}
```

Is it something as simple as I'm modifying an http block that gets overwritten by some other config file? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try "grep -r /var/log/nginx/access.log /etc/nginx" and "grep -r include /etc/nginx".

Comment: A "vanilla" installation may vary depending on what distro you are using, but it could be some file like /etc/nginx/conf.d/default specifying how the default vhost should work.

Comment: "grep -r /var/log/nginx/access.log /etc/nginx" returns nothing and "grep -r include /etc/nginx" returns "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf: include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf: #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf: include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf: include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;"

Comment: Thanks for the input. It's an ubuntu distro. No files in conf.d.

Comment: maybe you have a /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default file then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't your access_log also defined in a server block ? Have a look at the default config in nginx/sites-enabled/. 
In this case the value in http block is overwritten by the one in the lower block.

Comment: Thanks! I needed to put the change to the access log in the server block. To alter the format of the log, I had to put a log_format line in the nginx.conf http block and now everything is working as expected.